# Abbyy ocr android Unspecified Link error

Tags: android, ocr, abbyy

followed the abbyy setup for the wrapper for android. Obviously missed something in the setup beacuse I get the following error when creating an instance of the engine.

Getting the following error when executing the following code in android:

```
   final AssetDataSource ad = new AssetDataSource(ctx.getAssets());

   final List<DataSource> dataSources =  new ArrayList<DataSource>();
   dataSources.add(ad);
   DataFilesExtensions dfe = new DataFilesExtensions(".mp3",".mp3",".mp3");
   String LicenseFile = "";
          try {


                 Engine.createInstance(dataSources, new FileLicense(ad,LicenseFile,appID),dfe);
```

Produces the following error(logcat):

```
01-09 20:54:49.405: W/dalvikvm(3514): No implementation found for native Lcom/abbyy/mobile/ocr4/DataArray;.create (I)Z
01-09 20:54:49.522: E/DataArray(3514): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: create
01-09 20:54:49.522: W/dalvikvm(3514): No implementation found for native Lcom/abbyy/mobile/ocr4/DataArray;.pushChunk ([BI)V
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the issue is connected with accidentally added the assets as links instead of using copy. Eclipse does not show they as links. When your directory structure changed all those links were broke. After copying over the asset files you needed and renaming them to mp3 everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Something that's not really clear in the wrapper setup is the names of the resource files prior to moving and renaming them. There's europen.rom, english.edc and then there's a folder named BcrData with a a file english.akw. Which files should be copied where?

SL

Comment: figured out the filenames issue but still get the the following error on Engine create after copying the resource files to the correct directories.

Comment: error is:01-11 05:43:34.671: W/dalvikvm(5680): No implementation found for native Lcom/abbyy/mobile/ocr4/DataArray;.create (I)Z
01-11 05:43:34.772: E/DataArray(5680): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: create
01-11 05:43:34.772: W/dalvikvm(5680): No implementation found for native Lcom/abbyy/mobile/ocr4/DataArray;.pushChunk ([BI)V

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to call `Engine.loadNativeLibrary();` before calling `Engine.createInstance();`.